# Why superuser don't have global menu integration?

Tags: unity, sudo, appmenu

In Unity, when running an application as a superuser, the menu is in the old-style. It's not integrated in the global menu. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/592842/) and as such is now closed. For further information on this please follow the bug by selecting "This Affects Me".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug, but it hasn't had a status update in awhile.

> This is not supported at the moment. There are 2 aspects to this bug.
>
> The first aspect is that we use standard dbus calls, and don't
>   differentiate between the real and effective user id to connect to the
>   session bus. As a result, sudo apps are sharing a /distinct/ bus.
>   dbusmenu could workaround that potentially.
>
> The second aspect (more serious) is that the security implications
>   would probably dictate that menus of sudo apps be exposed with some
>   special color or rendering, to ensure the user is conscious that he is
>   interacting with privileged apps. That's more a design aspect.
>
> On the latter, you can argue however that sudo apps are currently
>   displayed as normal apps, so the solution for that design is actually
>   a more general problem to address.

*Via [Launchpad Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/592842/)*